# htaccess rewriterule with ? arguments?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What am I doing wrong, here?

I've moved to a new Web store platform (OSCommerce to Drual/Ubercart).  OSCommerce uses arguments to pick out products.

I want to redirect from this:

http://www.ztwistbooks.com/oscstore/product_info.php?products_id=64

To this:

http://www.ztwistbooks.com/node/39

This does NOT work (it gives a 404):

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$

RewriteRule ^oscstore/product_info.php\?products_id\=64$ "http\://www.ztwistbooks.com/node/39" [R=302,L]`

Other rewrite rules are fine, for instance, I can redirect stuff that doesn't use the ?arg=value, and it works fine:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.$

RewriteRule ^oscstore/?(.)$ "http\://www.ztwistbooks.com/index.php" [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule`'s pattern is applied to the URL-path, so you need something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^products_id=64$
RewriteRule ^oscstore/product_info.php$ http://www.ztwistbooks.com/node/39 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: That's very useful information, but it's still giving me a 404, even after I tried escaping the dots and slashes.

Comment: So, it does not match this rule at all?

Comment: Try to add `RewriteLog /path/to/file` and `RewriteLogLevel 9` to your config to see what's happening when mod_rewrite attempts this rule

Comment: This seems to do it:
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} products_id=64<br>
RewriteRule ^ http\:\/\/www\.ztwistbooks\.com\/node\/39? [R=301,L]`

I'm still having trouble with other rules, though.  I'll try your debug stuff.